# C# Application dealing with web request headers

Tags: c#, javascript, httpwebrequest, key-value, webrequest

Currently working on a project with a yahoo email manager, and I am trying to replicate a request header I've captured in Fiddler. Many of the variables I scrape beforehand from a previous GET response, but there's one that I can't figure out how is being generated.

It's a key-value pair with the key being "rand" and the value a 13 digit number. Reading through a response before making this request there are a lot of similar numbers (same first 4-5 digits) that seem to be related with a serverTime variable. I'm just unsure how to go about finding how this is generated. Is this usually found in a javascript file?

If what I wrote is unclear above, this is what I am trying to replicate:

Creating this URL so I can POST to it

```
http://us-mg5.mail.yahoo.com/ws/mailPreferences/v1/jsonrpc?appid=YahooMailOptions&wssid=inHNvViK&ymreqid=13e9d8d-bf26-45-010008010000&rand=1410343316407
```

wssit & reqid are found in a response before, but I don't know how to generate the rand variable.

This is the response where I find the variables http://pastebin.com/aMkHvjka

There are values that have similar numbers (first 4-5, 141034.....) and they relate to a variable called st, but I just don't know how to create the right one. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Why? Yahoo now support IMAP. You should check it out before going any further with your reverse engineering endeavours.

Comment: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mobile-mail/imap-server-settings-sln4075.html

Comment: The specific problem I am trying to solve can't be done with IMAP, but thank you for the reply.